# VBA : Using Public variables for other subs

Tags: vba, excel, variables, public

Excel-VBA. I want to create a variable that I will use in a couple of other subs later. Following other questions on this I declared the variable publicly

```
Public Counter As Integer
```

Then, I proceeded to give a value to the variable using a sub

```
Sub Count()
Set sh2= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rng As Range
Dim trng As Range
Set trng = sh2.Range("A4:HV4")

For Each rng In trng
    If rng.Value = "Name" Then
    Counter = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToLeft)).Columns.count
    End If
Next rng
```

If I try to test on the same sub which value count has e.g.

```
sh1.range("B1").value = counter
```

I get the right number.

However, once I try calling it on another sub, the value is 0!

```
Sub Test()

Range("F1").Value = counter

end sub
```

I have also tried calling the Count sub on my test sub, but also no result.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I allways use the "overkill" approcah, I just add a dedicated module (I call it _Global_Var_) and there I declare all my Global variables. In your example `Global Counter As Integer`.

Comment: There is no obvious error in the parts of the code you have included here, so the problem is in some other part of what you are doing. But I notice that Counter is capitalized in one place, not in others: either you have copied incorrectly, or the code display parser thinks that they are different variables.

Answer (score 2):

@ShaiRado already pointed it out in the comments. Below are some details around that :

**`Public`** types doesn't have visibility through out the VBA project, atleast not without their Object reference. So, If you declare a variable as `Public` inside a worksheet object\ UserForm \ Class, you need to use full reference for that variable. e.g if `Counter` is declared inside Sheet1 then use `Sheet1.Counter`.

**`Global`** variables on the other hand are accesible through out the VBA project. You dont need to call their parent  object names for refernce. Just one catch here, `Global` variables can only be declared inside Standard Modules.  object\ UserForm \ Class, they don't allow global variable declaration inside them.

In case of requirements for Project wide access, always declare `Global`.

Another thing is **`Option Explicit`**, if you had it in your code, instead of unexpected output/behavior you woud have got the error `Variable not defined` with codde highlihgted at

> Range("F1").Value = counter

That would have made debugging much easier. :)

Answer (score -1):

So, I solved it by simply calling the function before my new sub!

```
Sub Test()
Call count()
Range("F1").Value = counter

end sub
```